# Move filter-hide button to right - React-admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

Is there a way how to move filter close button to the right side of the input in React Admin ? 
Currently it appears always on left which is not really user friendly.

Or at least remove the button at all so I can create a custom component ?

```
<Filter {...props} variant="standard">
  <SelectInput source={source} label={label} choices={choices}/>
</Filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you add float: right, styling to the filter.

```
<Filter style={ { float: 'right'} } {...props} variant="standard">
  <SelectInput source={source} label={label} choices={choices}/>
</Filter>
```